Prevent emacs from automatically overwriting non-current auto-save file
I wanted to recover a file after a little unexpected shutdown.
So I opened the file in Emacs and ran recover-this-file.
Emacs responded with Auto-save file not current - fine, I thought, let me look into the folder for the filename mentioned. At that point I found out the Emacs had already overwritten the previous auto-save file with the autogenerated contents of the empty file I had just opened, so it seems my text would have still been there but is now gone...
Is there some sensible way to prevent this? Maybe moving the previous file over to /tmp when overwriting so it stays available until reboot?
